# Help with install kde on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: kde

I was installing kde on my laptop all went well until, I restarted my laptop and was greeted with this:

[image]

I tried hitting arrow keys and hitting enter it seemed like it was going through menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your display got ****ed up with the new installation of KDE.. What I would recommend is booting into Recovery mode using GRUB, and reverting to the last version, and setting display settings to original, also make sure your display manager is up to date. Anything else, just reply.